# Array::Utils what does this perl blurb do?

Tags: perl

I have been staring at this code (from Array::Utils:array_diff) :

```
sub array_diff(\@\@) {
    my %e = map {$_=>1} @{$_[1]};
    return @{[ ( grep { !delete $e{$_} } @{ $_[0] } ), keys %e ] };
}
```

Can somebody please breakdown the 2nd line of the subroutine for me? Where can i find additional grep documentation for the syntax used above? I understand the first line where a hash is created  out of the second argument passed to the method.

Comment: [Set Difference](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29#Relative_complement)

Comment: You can find additional information on grep here
http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/grep.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
return @{
    [ 
        (
            grep {
                !delete $e{$_}
            }
            @{ $_[0] }
        ),
        keys %e
    ]
};
```

For every entry `$_` in `@{ $_[0] }`, delete the associated hash key from `%e`.

`delete` should return (in scalar context) the value of the last element deleted.  In this case, if the key is found, the value will be `1`.  If the key isn't found, it'll return `undef`.  These values will be negated by the `!` such that, if it's *not* found we'll get a `1` (true), and if it *is* found we get `''` (false).  So that'll pick out all the items in `@{ $_[0] }` that *aren't* in `keys %e`, and then it appends all of *the remaining* keys from `%e` to that list.

It's all tucked into an anonymous array (`[ ... ]`) which is dereferenced with `@{ ... }`.

Comment: What's the point of wrapping it in `[`...`]` just to turn around and dereference it with `@{`...`}`?  Why not just return the inner array directly?

Comment: I believe that's to force `return` to treat the return value as an *array* instead of a *list* in scalar context. If someone were to want the number of differences (`$foo = array_diff(@one, @two)`), a list would return the right-most value and an array would return the size of the array.

Comment: (In this case, the right-most value being the scalar context of `keys %e`.)

Comment: @JimDavis/choroba, brilliant! Thank you! My use case is to take the "keys" from 2 hashes(OLD and NEW) and compare the deltas. It was possible to lose some keys in hash OLD and some new keys to be added to hash NEW. I wanted to get this info. Based on your explanation, I took out the ", keys %e" to get only those keys that did not exist. This helped me to get what i wanted. This sub is fast (I had a (2*n)**2 solution. wow, thanks gentlemen

Comment: @daazakali: For hashes, you can use a different approach: `my %deleted = %old; delete @deleted{ keys %new }; my %added = %new; delete @added{ keys %old };`.

Answer (score 3):

Jim Davis' answer is good and he answered first, so you should accept his answer. But I'm going to put my own spin on things anyway just in an attempt to expand on it and maybe teach some fishing.

When disentangling a complex expression, I find it's helpful to work from the inside out.  So let's start with the innermost value:

```
$_[0]
```

That's just the first argument to the subroutine.  The signature `(\@\@)` means that it's written to take two arrays and turn them into references, so you can call `array_diff @foo, @bar` and it will behave as if you'd written `array_diff \@foo, \@bar` or `array_diff [@foo], [@bar]`. It's therefore safe to assume that both `$_[0]` and `$_[1]` are array references.

The first line of code, as you stated, dereferences the second array and turns it into a hash of its unique elements. We're not doing that here, but we still need to dereference the first array to get its elements back out:

```
@{ $_[0] }
```

We then pass that list of elements to `grep`:

```
grep { ... } @{ $_[0] }
```

This will run the code represented by `...` on each element of the list and return a new list containing only the elements for which that code returns a true value.  So let's look inside the block and see what the code actually is:

```
!delete $e{$_}
```

That will (attempt to) delete any element whose key is `$_` (that is, the current element of `@{$_[0]}`) out of the hash `%e` (which was constructed from `@{$_[1]}`). If the element is not found, the `delete` will return `undef` (false), and the `!` will turn that into 1 (true). So the block will return a true value only for the elements that the `delete` fails on. That means the `grep` will return only those elements that *don't* exist in the hash (and therefore, didn't exist in the second array). As a side effect, moreover, all the elements that exist in *both* arrays - which are not returned by the `grep` - will also be deleted from the hash.

Note that this idiom only works because the code that populated `%e` set all of the values to 1, which is a true value.  A successful `delete` returns the deleted value, so if any of those hash values were false, the associated keys would be included in the result of the `grep` even though they had been in the second array.

We then append the keys that are still in the hash to the end of the list returned by the `grep`:

```
( grep { !delete $e{$_} } @{$_[0]} ), keys %e
```

This expression represents our desired return value: all the elements that are in only one of the two arrays. To the left of the comma are the elements in the first array but not the second (returned by the `grep`); to the right, the elements in the second array but not the first (put into `%e` and not deleted by the `grep`).

The parentheses around the `grep` call are needed because of precedence.  Perl will just keep building a list as long as it sees more commas, so without the parentheses, the expression would be interpreted like this:

```
  grep { !delete $e{$_} } ( @{$_[0]}, keys %e )
```

which is not what we want at all, since that will delete *everything* from `%e` and return just elements that appear only in the first array.

So if that's our desired result, we can just return it and we're done, right?  Right - as long as the subroutine is called in list context. But if it's called in scalar context, the caller will get only the last element of the difference list - probably not the most helpful behavior for this routine in that circumstance.

Putting the list into an anonymous array and then dereferencing that array is pointless busywork in list context, but it ensures that in scalar context, the return value of the subroutine is the number of elements in the list, instead of a particular element (randomly selected, at that, since hash keys are unordered).

The construction of an array is the key to the correct scalar context behavior; it need not be an anonymous one. So you could also do this:

```
return my @result = ( grep { !delete $e{$_} } @{ $_[0] } ), keys %e;
```

Although that might lead someone to "optimize" the code by removing the extra variable.

Comment: Very Helpful - your detailed summary cemented it permanently. These 2 responses are keepers. Thank you for taking the time and putting in the extra effort.